# selecting photos from google photos crushes my app

Tags: java, android, google-photos

i'm writing an android app on java and need to let my users select and crop images from the gallery.
There is no problem when choosing an image from any native gallery, but when a user chooses to eater crop or choose an image from google photos app the app crushes.

I cannot figure out what is the source of the problem so any answer will be helpful

this is the code i'm using
class fields:

```
private Uri imageUri;
```

opening the camera:

```
private void camOpen() {
    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "file" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png");
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    i.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_CODE);
}
```

opening the gallery:

```
private void galleryOpen() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "select file"), SELECT_PHOTO_CODE);
    }
```

cropping the image:

```
private void cropImage() {
    try {
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", true);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_CODE);

    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

the result handler:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        cropImage();
    } else if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            cropImage();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CROP_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap b = bundle.getParcelable("data");
        hasImageChanged=true;
        ivProfilePic.setImageBitmap(b);
        capturedImage = b;
    }
}
```

thank you for any useful help...

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: i'm using
"com.android.camera.action.CROP" in the intent constructor and that works fine for cropping images chosen from my phones gallery

Comment: There are ~2 billion Android devices. You are testing 1. Please do not assume that undocumented, unsupported things that happen to work on your device will work on everyone else's.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support crop intent because croping is not part of android api.
[So i recommend you for Using library](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with the crop intent. I ended up using the uCrop library and it fixed the problem.